# Shared data b/w AIR and Android app

Tags: android, air, shared-data

We are facing the issue of writing into android database (created by our app) from flash application (our another AIR app). From android point of view this will go against the security model by which each application process should not access resources of other application process.

Proper workaround would be to share same linux userid for both the applications (android as well as flash air app). By doing this both the applications are treated as same application with same file permission. We can use `sharedUserId` attribute in android manifest file to achieve this.

Can we set `sharedUserId` in android AIR application? What are the other workarounds for a AIR application to access database of a DalvikVM App?